# Краш при запуске примера из библиотеки SlyceMessaging

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь оседлать библиотеку [SlyceMessaging](https://github.com/Slyce-Inc/SlyceMessaging) Имею такой XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:name="it.slyce.messaging.SlyceMessagingFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/messaging_fragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

И вот такой OnCreate:

```
SlyceMessagingFragment slyceMessagingFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    slyceMessagingFragment = (SlyceMessagingFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.messaging_fragment);
    slyceMessagingFragment.setDefaultAvatarUrl("https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/10989174_799389040149643_722795835011402620_n.jpg?oh=bff552835c414974cc446043ac3c70ca&oe=580717A5");
    slyceMessagingFragment.setDefaultDisplayName("Matthew Page");
    slyceMessagingFragment.setDefaultUserId("uhtnaeohnuoenhaeuonthhntouaetnheuontheuo");

    slyceMessagingFragment.setOnSendMessageListener(new UserSendsMessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUserSendsTextMessage(String text) {
            Log.d("inf", "******************************** " + text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserSendsMediaMessage(Uri imageUri) {
            Log.d("inf", "******************************** " + imageUri);
        }
    });

    slyceMessagingFragment.setLoadMoreMessagesListener(new LoadMoreMessagesListener() {
        @Override
        public List<Message> loadMoreMessages() {
            ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                messages.add(getRandomMessage());
            return messages;
        }
    });

    slyceMessagingFragment.setMoreMessagesExist(true);
}
```

Проблема в том что на этой строке происходит краш:

```
slyceMessagingFragment.setDefaultAvatarUrl("https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/10989174_799389040149643_722795835011402620_n.jpg?oh=bff552835c414974cc446043ac3c70ca&oe=580717A5");
```

Код ошибки:

```
08-27 12:34:52.066 20799-20799/com.example.jack.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.jack.myapplication, PID: 20799
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jack.myapplication/com.example.jack.myapplication.Test}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void it.slyce.messaging.SlyceMessagingFragment.setDefaultAvatarUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void it.slyce.messaging.SlyceMessagingFragment.setDefaultAvatarUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.jack.myapplication.Test.onCreate(Test.java:65)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас NPE, а именно - ваш фрагмент равен null, т.к. не был найден в контейнере с указанным ID.

Вам надо задать ID родительскому контейнеру фрагмента и искать ваш фрагмент там.

Comment: id задан, slyceMessagingFragment = (SlyceMessagingFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.messaging_fragment); или речь не об этом?

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, нет не задан. Он у вас задан у фрагмента, а надо у контейнера, который содержит ваш фрагмент. Метод findFragmentById ищет фрагменты, которые находятся внутри контейнера с указанным ID. Вы же пытаетесь найти фрагмент в нём самом, а он фрагмента вашего сам в себе не содержит

Comment: Изменил XML всё равно ошибка <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/par">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="it.slyce.messaging.SlyceMessagingFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/messaging_fragment"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: А ищете по ID контейнера уже? по par?

Comment: Да ищу именно  по par

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, возможно, поможет смена `getFragmentManager()` на `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: нет не помогло пишет inconvertible types

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, в общем, у вас не находится фрагмент. Просто так это не происходит. Проверьте ещё раз правильную ли вы разметку установили. Также дело может быть в InstantRun опции студии - отключите её.